# Newest Mac Mini and VGA monitor won't work via MiniDisplayPort to VGA adapter

Tags: mac-mini, thunderbolt, displayport, vga-adapter

I've recently bought a new Mac Mini and tried to connect it to an old LG Flatron 19" VGA monitor. For that I've ordered a MiniDisplayPort to VGA adapter. Unluckily, this didn't work, monitor just doesn't seem to receive signal. I'm sure the monitor is OK, Mac was tested with another monitor and works fine, so there are probably two possibilities:

1. The adapter is broken
2. Somehow the monitor doesn't work with the Mac

I've searched Google and have found out that it's a known issue, but I struggled to find any working solution for this problem. Dealing with Apple's tech support is problematic for me, cause there are no Apple centers in my country. Is there any cure for this thing, or should I consider that the adapter is not working and buy another one? Thanks in advance for any information.

Comment: Is the known issue with this type of adapter or connecting the monitor to a Mac?

Comment: @Thorgrim, It's the issue of the adapter, I've found lots of posts about people not being able to connect a Mac to a monitor or a projector, but no working solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could try an HDMI to VGA converter like the [Kanex ATVPRO](http://www.kanexlive.com/atvpro).  I would not try one of the cheap cables that go straight from HDMI to VGA.

Verify that the converter produces a suitable resolution for your monitor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I was thinking that the adapter itself might be broken, but I could not prove it. Probably I should go with HDMI to VGA.